# selected item not shown in drop down list

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
   <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7"> 
   <select class="tblselect2 ">
   <option value="">Item 1</option>
   <option value="">Item 1</option>
    </select>
   </div>
```

I am using this CSS for formatting the `select` `option`.

```
.tblselect2 {

    background: url("../images/arrow1.png") no-repeat scroll right center white;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0 17px 0;
line-height: 1.5;
border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #555555;
    width: 64%;
}
```

When I am using this css the selected value does not come into the select box. I need to add this css however, for formatting the select button. I need to add a image for right drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hiding because of the height and padding you have used in your CSS. Update your CSS like below.

```
.tblselect2 {
background: url("../images/arrow1.png") no-repeat scroll right center white;
font-size: 12px;
height: 24px;
line-height: 1.5;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 2px 0 4px 0;
line-height: 1.5;
border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #555555;
width: 64%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want hide the original arrow of selectbox use the following CSS. But this solution will work onlly IE10+ browsers, chrome. IE older browser it wont work.

```
.tblselect2 {
background: url("http://www.fifa.com/imgml/icons/events/arrow_Down_Red.gif") no-repeat 99% 5px white;
font-size: 12px;
height: 24px;
line-height: 1.5;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 2px 0px 4px 0;
line-height: 1.5;
border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #555555;
width: 64%;
appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
-webkit-appearance:none;
} 
.col-lg-7 select::-ms-expand{
display: none;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vg2Bh/2/)

Comment: what?? check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/vg2Bh/ Same code i used here.

Comment: yes but i also want my arrow image at the place of default select arrow. when i remove padding the arrow image not show .

Comment: In this case you need to use appearance property. I have updated my answer with this. check it out.

Comment: thanks but i saw arrow didn't change.. please see again

Comment: Updated answer. will work in IE also now. Looks like mozilla have this bug itself. cehck out this article https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849

Comment: not working u have any other solution please tell me ..i need to add a arrow icon on select box

Comment: did you read my comments. what is the meaning of not working? i also told it wont work. any other solution? well check it out google for jquery custom selectbox.

Comment: yes i read u said its also work in IE . but its not working thats why i asked u. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Adjust Following  line in your css code and give height

```
  padding: 2px 0 10px 0;
  height:30px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/58KmZ/2/

Comment: but i need to padding whats is the solution of replace this padding.

Comment: u can see there image are not show when we remove padding

Comment: i need to this image for replace the select right button

Comment: give height:30px also  and reduce padding-bottom to 12 px..check this http://jsfiddle.net/58KmZ/1/

Comment: yes but what i want this is not . i also want my arrow image the place of select arrow.

Answer (score 0):

remove padding from your css code

```
padding:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the height and decrease the padding-bottom. If you change, it will be shown.

```
height: 25px;
padding: 2px 0px 5px 0px;
```